# I had bitcoin stored on my phone, but then lost my phone, please help

Tags: wallet-recovery, theft, coinomi

I had some bitcoins stored on my cell phone, but then it was stolen from me. How can I recover the bitcoins? Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to hear that you have had your device stolen. When using Coinomi all you need to be able to restore your funds on a new device is the 24word recovery phrase which you were given when you set up your wallet. You can learn more about this [here](https://coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000019254)

> Since Coinomi is an HD wallet, all you need as a backup is your Recovery Phrase

...

> If you ever lose or change phones, or want to use multiple devices at the same time, simply install Coinomi and choose the option "restore a wallet" and input all words in order. Make sure all characters are typed in lowercase and that there is a single space between each word. Type the first 3 or 4 letters of each word and select the suggestion that pops up to avoid misspellings.

Please open a ticket on that site if you require further support. Thank you

Comment: You should include the important and relevant content from the link in your answer - stackexchange aims to avoid link-only answers as they tend to be useless once the linked content is deleted or updated.